# Regex to get non-alphanumeric strings between alphanumeric strings

Tags: python, regex

Let say I have this string:

```
Alpha+*&Numeric%$^String%%$
```

I want to get the non-alphanumeric characters that are between alphanumeric characters:

```
+*& %$^
```

I have this regex: `[^0-9a-zA-Z]+` but it's giving me

```
+* %$^ %%$
```

which includes the tailing non-alphanumeric characters which I do not want. I have also tried `[0-9a-zA-Z]([^0-9a-zA-Z])+[0-9a-zA-Z]` but it's giving me

```
a+*&N c%$^S
```

which include the characters `a`, `N`, `c` and `S`

Comment: @ggorlen Yes. Edited

Comment: Where are the spaces coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind including the `_` character as alpha-numeric data, you can extract all your non-alpha-numeric-data with this:

```
some_string = "A+*&N%$^S%%$"

import re
result = re.findall(r'\b\W+\b', some_string)  # sets result to:  ['+*&', '%$^']
```

Note my use of `\b` instead of something like `\w` or `[^\W]`.

`\w` and `[^\W]` each match one character, so if your alpha-numeric string (between the text you want) is exactly one character, then what you think should be the next match won't match.

But since `\b` is a zero-width "word boundary," it doesn't care how many alpha-numeric characters there are, as long as there is at least one.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with your second attempt is the location of the `+` qualifier--it should be inside of the parentheses. You can also use the word character class `\w` and its inverse `\W` to pull out these items, which is the same as your second regex but includes underscores `_` as parts of words:

```
import re

s = "Alpha+*&Numeric%$^String%%$"

print(re.findall(r"\w(\W+)\w", s))                             # adds _ character
print(re.findall(r"[0-9a-zA-Z]([^0-9a-zA-Z]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]", s)) # your version fixed
print(re.findall(r"(?i)[0-9A-Z]([^0-9A-Z]+)[0-9A-Z]", s))      # same as above
```

Output:

```
['+*&', '%$^']
['+*&', '%$^']
['+*&', '%$^']
```